# how to contain a *.tpl file in a php variable?

Tags: php, excel, smarty

What I'm trying to do is to email an excel file as an attachment that's created out of a smarty tpl file, so currently this is what i'm doing:

```
    $smarty->display('export-report.tpl');
    $name=str_replace(" ","",$_POST['catname'])."_".date('d-m-Y');
    Header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    Header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$name.".xls");
```

But what I want to do next is instead of downloading that excel file directly from the browser I want to attach it and send it in an email, in order to do that I am saving the file first on my server and to create that excel file I need the content of the excel (the html contained in the tpl file) to be inside a php variable.

So my question is how do I get this:

```
$smarty->display('export-report.tpl');
```

To be contained in a variable like this:

```
$content
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `fetch` method this way:

```
$content = $smarty->fetch('export-report.tpl');
```

**EDIT**

Maybe what you want is simply changing the order this way:

```
$name=str_replace(" ","",$_POST['catname'])."_".date('d-m-Y');
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$name.".xls");
$smarty->display('export-report.tpl');
```

or

```
$content = $smarty->fetch('export-report.tpl');
$name=str_replace(" ","",$_POST['catname'])."_".date('d-m-Y');
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$name.".xls");
echo $content;
```

Comment: That grabs the HTML contained in that tpl as text, but what I'm after is kind of displaying it in the excel spreadsheet. Same as what I was doing with changing the content type and letting the user download a spreadsheet that displays that html.

Do you get my point?